# Adding Google Play Services to Android project

Tags: java, android, eclipse

SOLUTION FOUND--- check bottom

I know there are plenty of questions similar to mine but I have been working on this for days and cannot figure out how to get this working.

I am trying to incorporate Google Play Services into my application to use the push notifications.

Here is what I did so far:

1. Created a brand new project
2. Imported "google-play-services_lib" and chose to "Copy projects into workspace"
3. Went into Project -> Properties and added Google-play-services_lib under the "Library" section
4. Added the following code to my project.properties

   proguard.config=${sdk.dir}/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt:proguard-project.txt

   ## Project target.

   target=android-20
   android.library.reference.1=..\appcompat_v7
   android.library=true
   android.library.reference.2=..\google-play-services_lib
5. Added the following code to MainActivity.java's onCreate function:

   int status =  GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(getBaseContext());
   if (status == ConnectionResult.SUCCESS){
   Log.v("Play","AVAILABLE!!!!");
   }
   else{
   ((Dialog)GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(status, this,10)).show();
   }

And when I run my program I get

```
10-06 19:23:40.733: I/dalvikvm(16563): Could not find method com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable, referenced from method com.example.gcm_test.MainActivity.onCreate
10-06 19:23:40.733: W/dalvikvm(16563): VFY: unable to resolve static method 9321: Lcom/google/android/gms/common/GooglePlayServicesUtil;.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable (Landroid/content/Context;)I
10-06 19:23:40.733: D/dalvikvm(16563): VFY: replacing opcode 0x71 at 0x0014
10-06 19:23:40.823: V/Play(16563): LOG
10-06 19:23:40.823: D/AndroidRuntime(16563): Shutting down VM
10-06 19:23:40.823: W/dalvikvm(16563): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41786898)
10-06 19:23:40.823: E/AndroidRuntime(16563): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-06 19:23:40.823: E/AndroidRuntime(16563): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil
10-06 19:23:40.823: E/AndroidRuntime(16563):    at com.example.gcm_test.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:21)
10-06 19:23:40.823: E/AndroidRuntime(16563):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5372)
10-06 19:23:40.823: E/AndroidRuntime(16563):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1104)
10-06 19:23:40.823: E/AndroidRuntime(16563):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2267)
10-06 19:23:40.823: E/AndroidRuntime(16563):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2359)
10-06 19:23:40.823: E/AndroidRuntime(16563):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:165)
10-06 19:23:40.823: E/AndroidRuntime(16563):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1326)
10-06 19:23:40.823: E/AndroidRuntime(16563):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-06 19:23:40.823: E/AndroidRuntime(16563):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-06 19:23:40.823: E/AndroidRuntime(16563):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5455)
10-06 19:23:40.823: E/AndroidRuntime(16563):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-06 19:23:40.823: E/AndroidRuntime(16563):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
10-06 19:23:40.823: E/AndroidRuntime(16563):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1187)
10-06 19:23:40.823: E/AndroidRuntime(16563):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)
10-06 19:23:40.823: E/AndroidRuntime(16563):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-06 19:28:41.224: I/Process(16563): Sending signal. PID: 16563 SIG: 9
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

UPDATE:

I went into the appcompat_v7 libs folder and right clicked on each .jar file and clicked "Add to build" I also went into the "Order and Export" for this project and selected both jar files and deselected "Android Dependencies".

I did the same thing for the google-play-services_lib project.

I'm getting these error messages:

```
10-06 22:13:08.303: I/dalvikvm(24857): Could not find method com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable, referenced from method com.example.gcm_tester2.MainActivity.onCreate
10-06 22:13:08.303: W/dalvikvm(24857): VFY: unable to resolve static method 9321: Lcom/google/android/gms/common/GooglePlayServicesUtil;.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable (Landroid/content/Context;)I
10-06 22:13:08.303: D/dalvikvm(24857): VFY: replacing opcode 0x71 at 0x000d
10-06 22:13:08.434: D/AndroidRuntime(24857): Shutting down VM
10-06 22:13:08.434: W/dalvikvm(24857): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41786898)
10-06 22:13:08.434: E/AndroidRuntime(24857): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-06 22:13:08.434: E/AndroidRuntime(24857): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil
10-06 22:13:08.434: E/AndroidRuntime(24857):    at com.example.gcm_tester2.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:21)
10-06 22:13:08.434: E/AndroidRuntime(24857):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5372)
10-06 22:13:08.434: E/AndroidRuntime(24857):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1104)
10-06 22:13:08.434: E/AndroidRuntime(24857):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2267)
10-06 22:13:08.434: E/AndroidRuntime(24857):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2359)
10-06 22:13:08.434: E/AndroidRuntime(24857):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:165)
10-06 22:13:08.434: E/AndroidRuntime(24857):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1326)
10-06 22:13:08.434: E/AndroidRuntime(24857):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-06 22:13:08.434: E/AndroidRuntime(24857):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-06 22:13:08.434: E/AndroidRuntime(24857):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5455)
10-06 22:13:08.434: E/AndroidRuntime(24857):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-06 22:13:08.434: E/AndroidRuntime(24857):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
10-06 22:13:08.434: E/AndroidRuntime(24857):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1187)
10-06 22:13:08.434: E/AndroidRuntime(24857):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)
10-06 22:13:08.434: E/AndroidRuntime(24857):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

UPDATE 2:

Could anyone provide me with a print screen of what your pacakge explorer looks like when you did it correctly Like what should be under referenced libraries, android dependencies, etc. I'm getting so frustrated at this point

UPDATE 3:

So after days of researching I realized the problem was that **I needed to update my "Android SDK Build-tools".** OMG I GOT IT WORKING.

Comment: Try selecting the lib in 'Order and Export' where you added it to build path.

Comment: @svenoaks I'm sorry I don't understand what you mean? I'm very new to Android development..

Answer (score 0):

you need to add the library jars to build path;

you are missing few steps in adding the appcompat_v7 support library in eclipse. This is considered a library with resources, [please follow instructions under Eclipse here](https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html#libs-with-res)

Comment: Okay, I followed those steps for both the appcompat_v7 library and the google-play-services-lib and I'm still getting a bunch of error messages similar to before starting with Could not find method isGooglePlayServicesAvailable

Comment: please update your question with what you tried, and new error messages, as you make progress